# How to display success message if status code is 200

Tags: angular, api

Once i get response of status code 200 i need to show prompt message displaying product has been created successfully,
How can i manage this.

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifnKs.png]

component.ts

```
 addProduct() {
    this.body = {
      sku: this.skuFields.value,
      coffee: this.coffeeFields.value
    };
    console.log(this.body);
    this.addProductService.addProduct(this.body).subscribe(
      value => {
        if (value.status === 200) {
          console.log(value);
          }
    });
   }
```

service.ts

```
  addProduct(productFields) {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  });
  console.log('Create Product');
    return this.http.post(this.baseUrl, productFields);
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Did you check `value.statusCode` in console.log ?

Comment: You do not need to check for status code. subscribe has two arguments (success, failed). if 200, success callback is called, else goes to error callback. Simple use alert('product has been added') in the success callback. Or you can use ngx-toastr

check it for more details https://angular.io/guide/http#error-handling

Comment: the value.status is wrong you have statusCode in the response. it should be value.statusCode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it by changing condition. In response you are passing status on `statusCode` parameter and you are checking for `value.status` replace it with `value.statusCode`

```
this.addProductService.addProduct(this.body).subscribe(
      value => {
        if (value.statusCode === 200) {
          prompt('Success')
          }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your server is returning the status as part of the response body. In this case, you are checking the incorrect property. It should be `if (value.statusCode === 200)`.

In general, if you want the http client to return the whole response, you can set `observe` to `'response'` in the request options. You then get access to the response status, headers, body.

```js
ngOnInit() {
  const url = 'https://demo3909145.mockable.io/60829082';
  this.http.get(url, { observe: 'response' }).subscribe(response => {
    console.log(response.status); // 200
    const body = response.body;    
  });
}
```

Another thing to note is that your subscribe will only receive a value if the server response is a success (status codes 200 - 299). All other responses will come in as an error.

DEMO: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nt1ozu

Answer (score -1):

Your property in the response is `statusCode` and in your subscribe you are checking `value.status`. You must check `value.statusCode`.